# Dual X screens on one device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, multi-monitor, ubuntu-mate

I am using Ubuntu MATE 18.04.

I believe it uses LightDM as display manager.
I have 2 monitors connected to the same device (Intel HD onboard graphics, with 2 ports, one HDMI, one VGA).

Because of the nature of the applications I run, I need to have 2 separate X11 screens. I would need to move the mouse between them, but other than that they should be independent. I should not be able to move windows between monitors.

I believe that a setup with one display and 2 screens, with one monitor per screen, would work.

Using the display manager GUI app I just get a monitor as extended, and it is on the same screen.

- Am I correct that one display, with 2 screens, with one monitor per screen, would do what I want?
- And how would I set it up?

I'm following this guide:

- [Dual Monitors](http://web.archive.org/web/20130429073111/http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/Dual_Monitors#Single_graphics_card.2C_Multiple_X_screens_with_ZaphodHeads)
  (at the Gentoo Linux Wiki)

also

2. [Linux Multihead – More screens on one graphic card](http://www.odorik.cz/w/linux_multihead)
3. [Dual Screen Setup in Ubuntu with Intel HD Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278115/dual-screen-setup-in-ubuntu-with-intel-hd-graphics) (at Ask Ubuntu)
4. [Xorg: Independent Mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365796/xorg-independent-mode) (at Unix&Linux)
5. [Configuring Multiple X Screens on One Card](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.137/README/configmultxscreens.html)
   (at nvidia.com) (this does not mention ZaphodHeads)

It seams what I want is called ZaphodHeads – multiple screens with the same device.

However, the result I get is 2 blank screens with only the text cursor in the top left corner.

It seams to me this is the problem:

```
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 using monitor section MonitorR
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): EDID for output VIRTUAL1
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 disconnected
[    44.380] (WW) intel(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 disconnected
[    44.380] (WW) intel(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
```

My configuration:

`Xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr

VGA-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)    1920x1080     60.00 +    1600x1200     60.00      1680x1050     59.95  1400x1050     59.98      1600x900      60.00      1280x1024     75.02 
60.02      1440x900      59.89      1280x960      60.00      1360x768      59.95      1280x800      74.93    59.81      1152x864      75.00    59.97      1280x720      60.00      1024x768      75.03    60.00      800x600       75.00    60.32      640x480       75.00    59.94 

HDMI-1 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 673mm x 284mm    2560x1080     60.00*+    1920x1080    
60.00    50.00    59.94      1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94      1680x1050     59.88      1600x900      60.00      1280x1024     75.02 
60.02      1152x864      75.00      1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94      1024x768      75.03    60.00      800x600       75.00    60.32      720x576       50.00      720x480       60.00    59.94      640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94      720x400       70.08   DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

PCI device:

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga | cut -d " " -f 1 

00:02.0
```

`Xorg.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "LayoutDual"
    Screen      0  "ScreenR" 0 0
    Screen      1  "ScreenE" RightOf "ScreenR" EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "DefaultServerLayout" "LayoutDual" EndSection

Section "device"
    Identifier "IntelR"
    Driver     "intel"
    Option     "AccelMethod"    "sna"
    Screen     0
    BusId      "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option     "ZaphodHeads"    "HDMI-1"
    #Option     "NoAccel" "true" EndSection

Section "device"
    Identifier "IntelE"
    Driver     "intel"
    Option     "AccelMethod"    "sna"
    Screen     1
    BusId      "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option     "ZaphodHeads"   "VGA-1"
#    Option     "NoAccel" "true" EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "MonitorE"
    VendorName   "Vendor"
    ModelName    "Model"
    Option       "Rotate" "right" EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "MonitorR"
    VendorName   "Vendor"
    ModelName    "Model" EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier "ScreenE"
    Device     "IntelE"
    Monitor    "MonitorE"
    Option     "Rotate" "right"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "ScreenR"
    Device     "IntelR"
    Monitor    "MonitorR"
    DefaultDepth     24
#   Option      "DPI" "96 x 96"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
        Modes "2048x2048"
    EndSubSection EndSection
```

`Xorg log`:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log

[    44.028] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    44.028] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-138-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    44.028] Current Operating System: Linux simu 4.15.0-88-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 20:11:34 UTC 2020 x86_64
[    44.028] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-88-generic root=UUID=54ac0618-2b10-49ee-bca4-d9ba7634ed46 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    44.028] Build Date: 25 October 2018  04:11:27PM
[    44.028] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    44.028] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    44.028]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    44.028] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    44.028] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Feb 26 19:59:18 2020
[    44.043] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    44.043] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    44.091] (**) Option "defaultserverlayout" "LayoutDual"
[    44.091] (**) ServerLayout "LayoutDual"
[    44.091] (**) |-->Screen "ScreenR" (0)
[    44.091] (**) |   |-->Monitor "MonitorR"
[    44.091] (**) |   |-->Device "IntelR"
[    44.091] (**) |-->Screen "ScreenE" (1)
[    44.091] (**) |   |-->Monitor "MonitorE"
[    44.091] (**) |   |-->Device "IntelE"
[    44.091] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    44.091] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    44.091] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    44.091] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    44.091] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    44.103] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    44.103]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    44.103] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    44.103]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    44.103] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    44.103]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    44.103] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    44.103]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    44.103] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    44.103]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    44.103] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    44.103] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    44.103] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    44.103] (II) Loader magic: 0x557171c1d020
[    44.103] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    44.103]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    44.103]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    44.103]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    44.103]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    44.104] (++) using VT number 7

[    44.104] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    44.104] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    44.124] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0122:8086:2111 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7800000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    44.124] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    44.144] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    44.271] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    44.271]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    44.271]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    44.271] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    44.271] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    44.346] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    44.346]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 2.99.917
[    44.346]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    44.346]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    44.346] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    44.346] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    44.346] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    44.346] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    44.368] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20171023
[    44.368] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[    44.368] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    44.379] (II) intel(1): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20171023
[    44.379] (II) intel(1): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[    44.379] (II) intel(1): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    44.379] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000
[    44.379] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx; using a maximum of 4 threads
[    44.379] (**) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    44.379] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    44.379] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    44.379] (**) intel(0): Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
[    44.379] (**) intel(0): Option "ZaphodHeads" "HDMI-1"
[    44.380] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 using monitor section MonitorR
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): EDID for output VIRTUAL1
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 disconnected
[    44.380] (WW) intel(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[    44.380] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 disconnected
[    44.380] (WW) intel(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
[    44.380] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[    44.380] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    44.380] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    44.380] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[    44.380] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[    44.380] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[    44.380] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    44.380] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    44.380] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    44.380] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    44.380] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    44.380] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    44.380] (--) intel(1): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000
[    44.380] (--) intel(1): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx; using a maximum of 4 threads
[    44.380] (**) intel(1): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    44.380] (==) intel(1): RGB weight 888
[    44.380] (==) intel(1): Default visual is TrueColor
[    44.380] (**) intel(1): Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
[    44.380] (**) intel(1): Option "ZaphodHeads" "VGA-1"
[    44.380] (--) intel(1): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    44.380] (II) intel(1): Output VIRTUAL1 using monitor section MonitorE
[    44.381] (**) intel(1): Option "Rotate" "right"
[    44.381] (II) intel(1): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    44.381] (II) intel(1): EDID for output VIRTUAL1
[    44.381] (II) intel(1): Output VIRTUAL1 disconnected
[    44.381] (WW) intel(1): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[    44.381] (II) intel(1): Output VIRTUAL1 disconnected
[    44.381] (WW) intel(1): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
[    44.381] (==) intel(1): TearFree disabled
[    44.381] (==) intel(1): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    44.381] (==) intel(1): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    44.381] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[    44.381] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[    44.381] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[    44.381] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    44.381] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    44.381] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    44.381] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    44.381] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    44.381] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    44.381] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    44.434] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Sandybridge (gen6, gt2) backend
[    44.434] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    44.434] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    44.434] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    44.434] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    44.434] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    44.434] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    44.434] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[    44.434] (--) RandR disabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(1): SNA initialized with Sandybridge (gen6, gt2) backend
[    44.434] (==) intel(1): Backing store enabled
[    44.434] (==) intel(1): Silken mouse enabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(1): HW Cursor enabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(1): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    44.434] (==) intel(1): DPMS enabled
[    44.434] (==) intel(1): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(1): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    44.434] (II) intel(1): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    44.434] (II) intel(1): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    44.434] (II) intel(1): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[    44.434] (II) intel(1): hardware support for Present enabled
[    44.434] (WW) intel(1): Option "Rotate" is not used
[    44.434] (--) RandR disabled
[    44.463] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es{,2}_profile
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[    44.749] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[    44.749] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es{,2}_profile
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[    44.757] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[    44.757] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 1
[    45.054] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    45.054] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    45.054] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    45.054] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    45.095] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    45.095]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.27.1
[    45.095]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    45.095]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    45.095] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    45.095] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    45.095] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    45.095] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    45.095] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.095] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    45.095] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[    45.108] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    45.108] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    45.108] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    45.108] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    45.108] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.108] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    45.109] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event2)
[    45.109] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    45.109] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    45.109] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    45.109] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    45.109] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    45.109] (II) event2  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.109] (II) event2  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    45.109] (II) event2  - Video Bus: device removed
[    45.124] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input2/event2"
[    45.124] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    45.124] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    45.124] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    45.124] (II) event2  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.124] (II) event2  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    45.125] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    45.125] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    45.125] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    45.125] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    45.125] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    45.125] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    45.126] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.126] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    45.126] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[    45.140] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    45.140] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    45.140] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    45.140] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    45.141] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.141] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    45.142] (II) config/udev: Adding input device UC02 UC02 (/dev/input/event3)
[    45.142] (**) UC02 UC02: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    45.142] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'UC02 UC02'
[    45.142] (**) UC02 UC02: always reports core events
[    45.142] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    45.142] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    45.143] (II) event3  - UC02 UC02: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.143] (II) event3  - UC02 UC02: device is a keyboard
[    45.143] (II) event3  - UC02 UC02: device removed
[    45.156] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.3/0003:0000:0000.0001/input/input3/event3"
[    45.156] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "UC02 UC02" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    45.156] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    45.156] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    45.157] (II) event3  - UC02 UC02: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.157] (II) event3  - UC02 UC02: device is a keyboard
[    45.157] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event10)
[    45.157] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    45.157] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    45.158] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[    45.158] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    45.158] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    45.158] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[    45.158] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    45.158] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    45.159] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[    45.159] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    45.159] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    45.159] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event8)
[    45.160] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    45.160] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    45.160] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event9)
[    45.160] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    45.160] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    45.161] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Telink Wireless Receiver (/dev/input/event4)
[    45.161] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    45.161] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    45.161] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Telink Wireless Receiver'
[    45.161] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: always reports core events
[    45.161] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    45.161] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    45.162] (II) event4  - Telink Wireless Receiver: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    45.162] (II) event4  - Telink Wireless Receiver: device is a pointer
[    45.162] (II) event4  - Telink Wireless Receiver: device is a keyboard
[    45.162] (II) event4  - Telink Wireless Receiver: device removed
[    45.180] (II) libinput: Telink Wireless Receiver: needs a virtual subdevice
[    45.180] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/0003:248A:8367.0002/input/input4/event4"
[    45.180] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Telink Wireless Receiver" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[    45.180] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    45.180] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    45.180] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    45.180] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    45.181] (II) event4  - Telink Wireless Receiver: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    45.181] (II) event4  - Telink Wireless Receiver: device is a pointer
[    45.181] (II) event4  - Telink Wireless Receiver: device is a keyboard
[    45.182] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Telink Wireless Receiver (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    45.182] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    45.182] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    45.183] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Telink Wireless Receiver (/dev/input/event5)
[    45.183] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    45.183] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Telink Wireless Receiver'
[    45.183] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: always reports core events
[    45.183] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    45.183] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    45.184] (II) event5  - Telink Wireless Receiver: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.184] (II) event5  - Telink Wireless Receiver: device is a keyboard
[    45.184] (II) event5  - Telink Wireless Receiver: device removed
[    45.204] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/0003:248A:8367.0003/input/input5/event5"
[    45.204] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Telink Wireless Receiver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    45.204] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    45.204] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    45.205] (II) event5  - Telink Wireless Receiver: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.205] (II) event5  - Telink Wireless Receiver: device is a keyboard
[    45.213] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    45.213] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    45.213] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Telink Wireless Receiver'
[    45.213] (**) Telink Wireless Receiver: always reports core events
[    45.213] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    45.213] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[    45.213] (II) libinput: Telink Wireless Receiver: is a virtual subdevice
[    45.213] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/0003:248A:8367.0002/input/input4/event4"
[    45.213] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Telink Wireless Receiver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    45.213] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    45.213] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
```

The 2 screens are black with the cursor in the top left corner.

Do I need to configure LightDM to accept this?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to share the keyboard and mouse between the 2 monitors? If so, then what behaviour are you looking for?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. yes i should share keyboard and monitor. one "screen" per monitor. can move the mouse between monitors, but not any window.

Comment: No one has answered. I have only asked for clarification. Please **edit question** to clarify. Also **add information about what behaviour you would like to see**.

Comment: I have improved your question, based on your comment, and my guess at to what you are trying to do. Hope it is correct. It should now get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `startx`/`xinit` as single programs?

Kill LightDM, read the man page for `xinit` and then I think you should be
able to do what you want (no, I don't think LightDM is written to support this usage.)

It could include writing a customized `xorg.conf`.

Comment: yes im using a custom xorg.conf like this example
http://web.archive.org/web/20130429073111/http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/Dual_Monitors#Single_graphics_card.2C_Multiple_X_screens_with_ZaphodHeads
however im getting black screens at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I have lots of experience with the setup you want. You have to make custom xorg.conf. If you have Intel graphics adapter ZaphodHeads is your way to do it. Here is an example:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "LayoutDual"
    Screen      0  "ScreenR" 0 0
    Screen      1  "ScreenE" RightOf "ScreenR"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "DefaultServerLayout" "LayoutDual"
EndSection

Section "device"
    Identifier "IntelR"
    Driver     "intel"
    #Option     "AccelMethod"    "sna"
    Screen     0
    BusId      "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option     "ZaphodHeads"    "eDP1"
    Option     "NoAccel" "true"
EndSection

Section "device"
    Identifier "IntelE"
    Driver     "intel"
    Screen     1
    BusId      "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option     "ZaphodHeads"   "HDMI2"
    Option     "NoAccel" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "MonitorE"
    VendorName   "Vendor"
    ModelName    "Model"
    Option       "Rotate" "right"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "MonitorR"
    VendorName   "Vendor"
    ModelName    "Model"
EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier "ScreenE"
    Device     "IntelE"
    Monitor    "MonitorE"
    Option     "Rotate" "right"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "ScreenR"
    Device     "IntelR"
    Monitor    "MonitorR"
    DefaultDepth     24
#   Option      "DPI" "96 x 96"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth     24
        Modes "2048x2048"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Type `lspci` in command line to see where is your graphics adapter connected. It is defined in BusId. If you have more this can come very useful. It is optional, if you have only one. Type `xrandr`, to see which outputs are recognized by your driver. The accelerators are disabled in the example. You can enable them if you want. You can make more layouts, and then specify, which is going to be used in `DefaultServerLayout` section.

Here is a NVidia example:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "LayoutDual"
    Screen      0  "ScreenR" 0 0
    Screen      1  "ScreenL" LeftOf "ScreenR"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "unix/:7100"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "type1"
    Load  "freetype"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "DefaultServerLayout" "LayoutDual"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
    Option      "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option      "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "MonitorL"
    VendorName   "Vendor"
    ModelName    "Model"
    HorizSync    20.0 - 120.0
    VertRefresh  30.0 - 120.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "MonitorR"
    VendorName   "Vendor"
    ModelName    "Model"
    HorizSync    28.0 - 55.0
    VertRefresh  43.0 - 72.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DeviceL"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName   "Quadro FX 380"
    Option      "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP,CRT"
    Option      "UseDisplayDevice" "CRT-1"
    Option      "CustomEDID" "CRT-1:/etc/X11/ADP361.bin"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DeviceR"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName   "Quadro FX 380"
    Option      "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP,DFP"
    Option      "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP-0"
    Option      "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/ISIS.bin"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "ScreenL"
    Device     "DeviceL"
    Monitor    "MonitorL"
    DefaultDepth     24
    Option      "TwinView" "0"
    Option      "metamodes" "CRT-1: 1200x1920 +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "ScreenR"
    Device     "DeviceR"
    Monitor    "MonitorR"
    DefaultDepth     24
    Option      "TwinView" "0"
    Option      "metamodes" "DFP-0: 2048x2048 +0+0"
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. ive created a custom xorg.conf similar to that, however the results are blank screens. i will post the xorg.log soon, as ive seen some problems there

Comment: Post the xorg.conf. Inspect `/var/log/X?.xorg?.log` files. They usually offer a lot information what went wrong.

Comment: I'm running a similar set up and have been successful in getting a full desktop environment running on :0.0, but unsuccessful in having the desktop environment running successfully on both monitors. I'm on RHEL 8 and have tried many different desktops/window managers. Is there a trick to getting a full desktop environment up across both displays?

Comment: @Natolio That is strange. Lately, I have more problems running the desktop environment on only one screen. Have you tried to configure it with Xinerama (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama)?

Comment: @nobody I have not, but I do not think Xinerama will work for my use case. I need to be able to remotely launch applications to specific displays using DISPLAY=:0.X, and also need to be able to cycle through virtual desktops separately on each display. I have used Xinerama in the past and I do not remember it supporting either of those things.

Comment: @nobody I've finally gotten around to confirming that Xinerama just creates one display that spans both monitors. So that will not work for my usecase. Do you mind posting an nvidia xorg.conf config example?

Comment: @Natolio In the updated answer, you can find an example of two screen layout with nVidia. There are a lot of lines which you can delete/ignore (keyboard config, mouse config,...). I do not think everything is correct in the example, because some lines are repeated (ConnectedMonitor, etc.), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was on Debian-11 with Xfce and faced the same issue (two blank screens with cursor only). I managed to solve it by forcing to use the 'modesetting' drivers (instead of intel) in my xorg.conf, as follows

```
Section "Device"                                                                                                                                     
#   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
#   Driver     "intel"                                                                  
   Identifier "Modesetting"                                                                                                                
   Driver     "modesetting"
   Option "AccelMethod" "sna"                                                                                                                 
EndSection
```

Why did it solve my issue?

The error that I found in my xorg.log was the following

```
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
```

A google search for the above error message took me to

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/2926

Took some hints and gave it a try (though the page deals with a totally different issue) and Voila! it worked.