# Trying to capture one monitor with maim

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xrandr, bspwm

I have two monitors and I would like to only screenshot the main one, maim by default screenshots both monitors as one big monitor, and doing `maim -x :0.0` doesn't work. I'm trying to figure this out so I searched and found the commands `ls /tmp/.X11-unix` which returns `X0` and `ls /tmp/.X11-unix | tr 'X' ':'` which return `:0`. It looks like it's detecting both monitors as one or am I wrong? I did `xrandr | grep ' connected'` and it shows

```
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
DP-5 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
```

Please keep in mind I have no idea what I'm doing I'm very new to linux and I'm trying to learn it so I switched to it as my daily driver to learn. What can I do to be able to screenshot one monitor?

Comment: You have one "display" (:0) which is 3840x1080,displayed on two monitors. The manual page   I found online suggests that you want `maim -x 0 -y 0 -w 1920 -h 1080` or maybe `-x 1920` depending on which monitor you want.

Comment: Or `maim -g 1920x1080+1920+0` (copying the third field from the xrandr output).

Comment: @icarus how do I split it into two displays?

Comment: @Yousef, that's a bigger question.  One start at the answer is this question that was recently updated (and has links to similar questions):  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569434/dual-x-screens-on-one-device

Comment: Well maim -g 1920x1080+0+0 worked for the main monitor thank you. I'll look more into splitting the screen.

Comment: Usually you don't want to split it into two displays, you want to be able to seamlessly move windows from one monitor to another, and have apps which have two or more windows e.g. graphics or movie editors. have some windows on each monitor. **Most** applications only work with a single display. Why do you think having two displays will help? Note some window managers can help with a workflow that says "keep everything the same on the left monitor whilst I switch to a new desktop on the right monitor".